# Associate the "Visible" Parameter of a family element to a FamilyParameter

Tags: c#, revit-api

I am writing code to create a variable grid of lines (different number of columns or rows).  I want the "Visible" parameter of each line to be associated with a particular FamilyParameter.

```
switch (One_Param_Name)
{
    case "Use 2 Rows": { Part_Formula = "Rows = 2)"; break; }
    case "Use 3 Rows": { Part_Formula = "Rows = 3)"; break; }
    case "Use 4 Rows": { Part_Formula = "Rows = 4)"; break; }
    case "Use 5 Rows": { Part_Formula = "Rows = 5)"; break; }
    case "Use 6 Rows": { Part_Formula = "Rows = 6)"; break; }
    case "Use 2 Columns": { Part_Formula = "Columns = 2)"; break; }
    case "Use 3 Columns": { Part_Formula = "Columns = 3)"; break; }
    case "Use 4 Columns": { Part_Formula = "Columns = 4)"; break; }
    case "Use 5 Columns": { Part_Formula = "Columns = 5)"; break; }
    case "Use 6 Columns": { Part_Formula = "Columns = 6)"; break; }
    case "Use 7 Columns": { Part_Formula = "Columns = 7)"; break; }
    case "Use 8 Columns": { Part_Formula = "Columns = 8)"; break; }
    case "Use 9 Columns": { Part_Formula = "Columns = 9)"; break; }
    case "Use 10 Columns": { Part_Formula = "Columns = 10)"; break; }
}
FamilyParameter New_Param = Familial.AddParameter(One_Param_Name, Groupie, ParameterType.YesNo, true);
string ParamFormula = "and(Show Grid, Number Of " + Part_Formula;
if (!One_Param_Name.Equals("Show Grid"))
{
    Familial.SetFormula(New_Param, ParamFormula);
}
else
{
    Familial.Set(New_Param, 0);
}
```

Previously in the code, I have defined the integer parameters "Number Of Columns" and "Number Of Rows".  This code effectively creates a variable number of YesNo parameters which are controlled by formulas that say "If Grids are to be shown, and the number of columns is 7, set parameter to true".

Now, however, I want to set the visibility of individual lines in my family to the appropriate parameter (which you are able to do in the properties, "=" (Associate Family Parameter).  I have found the parameter method .AssociateWithGlobalParameter(gpid), which I could use if these were global, but the parameters are FamilyParameter, and there is not a similar .AssociateWithFamilyParameter(fpid) method.

Does anyone know of the method (if any) to associate a family element's visibility parameter (or other associable parameters) to a FamilyParameter?

NOTE:  The answer is to use FamilyManager in conjunction with Element.Parameters.  First, you must find the Element's "Visible" parameter.  Determine which FamilyParameter you want (IndexOf in a string list?).  And then:

```
FM.AssociateElementParameterToFamilyParameter(VisibleParam,FamilyParam);
```

Comment: Jeremy's answer provides the necessary information, with a little investigation.  Please note that the AssociateElementParameterToFamilyParameter is accessed via FamilyManager ...FM.AssociateElementToFamilyParameter(Element.Parameter,FamilyParameter) while the AssociateWithGlobalParameter was a property accessed via Element.Parameters.  Once you can identify both parameters, this works well.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [AssociateElementParameterToFamilyParameter method](http://www.revitapidocs.com/2017/a047ea58-0351-b419-d856-85ed23734ee8.htm), cf. the [Family API labs](http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2009/08/the-revit-family-api.html#4) sample, available in the updated [AdnRevitApiLabsXtra](https://github.com/jeremytammik/AdnRevitApiLabsXtra).